# O que é um iterador assíncrono em JavaScript? Qual a sua relação com laços “for await”?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

O que são iteradores assíncronos em JavaScript? Qual a sua função e quais são as diferenças entre o protocolo de iteração “convencional”?

Qual a sua relação com o `for await .. of`?

É possível usá-los (iteradores assíncronos) em um laço `for..of`? Quando é recomendado utilizar `for await .. of` ao invés de `for .. of`?

Comment: È a vontade do JS se transformar no C# :P Ele copia tudo :D Inclusive pode ser o motivo pras pessoas abusarem de *lambda* no JS. C# tem uma sintaxe simples pra métodos simples que não é *lambda*, JS, não tem, então a pessoa usa *lambda* pra simular, só que paga um preço por isso.

Comment: Estás a pensar em `function*` certo?

Comment: Não sei, até onde eu sei, `function*` é um gerador que cria um iterador “convencional”, certo?

Comment: Não, é uma função que pode ser chamada multiplas vezes com estado interno. Pode ser usada como iterador mais não é um iterador no termo de "processa cada um destes items". A minha dúvida é porque para mim _iterador assíncrono_  é por exemplo o `for...await` e `function*` é uma _função gerador_

Comment: Uma _stream_ pode ser vista como iterador assíncrono tb.

Comment: Acho que está mais ligado com o protocolo do que com essas construções, que implementam o protocolo.

Answer (score 1):

Se faz comum um cenário o qual precisamos chamar funções `async`/`await` em laços de repetição, por isso, no ES2018, o comitê do [TC39](https://tc39.es/) apresentou um novo símbolo, denominado `Symbol.asyncIterator`, bem como uma nova construção sintática, denominada `for await .. of`. Ambos nos ajudam com a facilidade para se executar laços de funções `async`/`await`.

A principal diferença entre os objetos denominados *regular iterators* e os *asynchronous iterators* é a seguinte:

#### Objeto iterador (*regular iterator*)

O método `next` de um objeto *iterator* retorna um valor como `{ value: 'X', done: false }`.

Por exemplo:

```
(E) >>> iterator.next()

(S) { value: 'X', done: false }
```

#### Objeto iterador assíncrono (*asynchronous iterator*)

O método `next` de um objeto *asynchronous iterator* retorna uma `Promise`, que depois será resolvida em algo como:

Por exemplo:

```
(E) >>> iterator.next()

(S) Promise { <fulfilled>: { value: 'X', done: false } }
```

É muito difícil responder a sua questão sobre qual iterador utilizar, pois para isso, devem ser feitas análises e estudos embasados, mas o que eu posso te responder é o seguinte:

Como eu disse acima, o próprio comitê do [TC39](https://tc39.es/) apresentou esse novo iterador (assíncrono) e, se ele foi criado, é porque diversos estudos foram feitos, então siga a documentação e fontes confiáveis como esta e não invente moda.

Uma dica que lhe dou para compreender mais este mundo de `async`/`await`, `iterators`, `symbols`, programação orientada a eventos é em uma biblioteca o qual utilizo bastante no *Angular*, a qual é denominada de [RxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/)!