# Qual objetivo da API Timers Promises no Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises

Recentemente, na versão [v16.0.0](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html) do Node.js, foi adicionado a API Timers Promises e, pelo que eu entendi, trata-se de *alterar* o comportamento dos timers padrões (`setTimeout`, `setImmediate`, etc...). Esses *timers* retornam objetos `NodeJS.Timeout`, desta forma:

Se feito um `console.log(setTimeout(() => {}, 0))`, temos:

```
Timeout {
  _idleTimeout: 1000,
  _idlePrev: [TimersList],
  _idleNext: [TimersList],
  _idleStart: 34,
  _onTimeout: [Function (anonymous)],
  _timerArgs: undefined,
  _repeat: null,
  _destroyed: false,
  [Symbol(refed)]: true,
  [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 7,
  [Symbol(triggerId)]: 0
}
```

Agora, graças a essa API, as novas funções retornam um objeto `Promise`.

Neste [exemplo](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timerspromises_settimeout_delay_value_options) (adaptado por mim) da documentação, temos:

```
import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises';

const twoSeconds = 2_000;

const res = await setTimeout(twoSeconds, 'result');

// Exibe a string "result" depois de 2 segundos.
console.log(res);
```

Essa função acima é bem mais simples e leva menos código pra se construir e entender. Vejam que essa função que retorna uma promessa, o que permite o uso do `await`. Essa nova API "meio que" faz uma "*promissificação*" do timer `setTimeout` por baixo dos panos.

No exemplo acima, se eu fizer um `console.log(setTimeout(() => {}, 0))`, terei no terminal:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Eu queria saber:

- Se essa "*promissificação*" dos timers é o principal propósito desta nova implementação.
- Ela resolve quais problemas?

---

Essa API foi inserida na versão v15.0.0 como *experimental* e foi estabilizada na versão v16.0.0 do Node.js.

Comment: Como boa parte das demais APIs do Node é baseada em promessas, acredito que tenham criado essa nova versão dos timers para facilitar o uso com essas outras APIs. Lembrando que a API "padrão" de timers do Node já não era padrão – e sim uma transposição da implementação que existe nos browsers, parte da API do DOM (acho).

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim! seria a API do `window` no caso? `setTimeout()` é semelhante a API `window.setTimeout` dos browsers.

Comment: Sim, é dessa mesmo que estou falando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem nenhum objetivo muito diferente das que já existem; a ideia é facilitar o uso dos *timers* em casos nos quais promessas são utilizadas. Decerto essas novas APIs têm aparecido com força no Node.js, como o próprio `fs/promises`.

Não vai alterar o comportamento das funções `setTimeout`, `setInterval` e `setImmediate` que já existem, até porque isso seria uma *breaking change* muito grande. O que irá ocorrer é o estabelecimento de três **novas** funções, de mesmo nome, qualificadas no módulo *nativo* `timers/promises`.

Da [documentação](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/timers.html#timers_timers_promises_api):

> A API `timers/promises` fornece um conjunto alternativo de *timer functions* que retornam objetos `Promise`.

É muito comum encontrar funções como:

```
function wait(interval = 0) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, interval));
}
```

Para criar uma função que retorna uma promessa que é automaticamente resolvida após determinado intervalo de tempo. Existem vários pacotes no npm com um número substancial de *downloads* que também fazem esse tipo de coisa.

A nova API do Node.js, totalmente baseada em promessas, torna esse tipo de funcionalidade "nativa". O interessante é que fornece meios para cancelamento e criação de intervalos que utilizam [iteradores assíncronos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/452791/69296), que não eram possíveis com funções simples como a `wait`, demonstrada acima.

Alguns exemplos:

1. #### Criação de um *timeout*

   Como alternativa ao `wait` proposto acima, agora é possível utilizar APIs nativas do Node.js:

   ```
   import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises';

   console.log('Foo');
   await setTimeout(1000); // Espera 1s
   console.log('Bar'); // Imprime `Bar` após 1s.
   ```

   Note que, como a nova API é baseada em promessas, o `await` pode ser utilizado em funções assíncronas ou *top-level module* para "aguardar" o *timeout*.
2. #### Criação de um intervalo

   Os intervalos criados pela API `timers/promises` faz uso de [iteradores assíncronos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator), devolvendo uma promessa a cada intervalo de tempo. Fica extremamente interessante com laços `for await .. of`:

   ```
   import { setInterval } from 'timers/promises';

   for await (const _ of setInterval(100)) {
     console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('pt-BR')); // Irá imprimir a cada 0.1s
   }
   ```
3. A [documentação](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/timers.html#timers_timers_promises_api) expande um pouco mais nos exemplos e argumentos de cada uma das três funções, `setImmediate`, `setTimeout` e `setInterval`.

---

É interessante mencionar que, como `setTimeout` e `setInterval` retornam promessas (e não um identificador), é necessário utilizar APIs como [`AbortController`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/globals.html#globals_class_abortcontroller) para realizar o cancelamento do temporizador.

Um exemplo usando `setInterval`:

```
import { setInterval, setTimeout } from 'timers/promises';

const controller = new AbortController();

setTimeout(500).then(() => {
  controller.abort();
});

let i = 0;

try {
  // O segundo argumento (passei `null`) é o valor
  // de resolução de cada promessa.
  for await (const _ of setInterval(100, null, { signal: controller.signal })) {
    console.log('Atual:', ++i);
  }
} catch (err) {
  if (err.code === 'ABORT_ERR') {
    console.log('Abortado!');
  }
}
```

No caso do `setInterval`, quando utilizado com laços `for await .. of`, também é possível utilizar o `break` para sair do laço e, portanto, finalizar o intervalo. Por exemplo:

```
import { setInterval } from 'timers/promises';

let i = 0;
for await (const _ of setInterval(100)) {
  console.log('Atual:', ++i);

  if (i === 5) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: FIquei curioso com esse  `AbortController`, vou dar uma olhada com calma. Uma pergunta, foi vc que perguntou como cancelar uma chamada assincrona com axios (eu acho) ou algo assim?

Comment: Foi o Wallace, @CmteCardeal! Mas fui eu quem [respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/480077/69296)!